# Management Action - macOS 10.15.7 Catalina showing Important Update alert

Tags: macos

Today I got this alert window as the posted pic below.
By clicking Submit, there's no response or restart automatically. I tried to restart manually the machine but a few moments later, it pops up again. Is there anyone who can help on it?

[image]

Comment: Looks suspicious (Maleware)! Try to identify the app who shows this dialog.

Answer (score 2):

That looks a lot like the Management Action dialog that Jamf's device management systems use (see [here](https://community.jamf.com/t5/jamf-pro/how-to-customize-management-action-window-message/td-p/223872) for an example). Is your Mac being managed by some company/school/etc you're associated with? If it is, it's probably the remote management admin "encouraging" you to install [Security Update 2021-006 for Catalina](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2085), which  just came out last week and does indeed [fix a critical vulnerability](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212825).

Since it doesn't seem to be working properly, I'd recommend just going into the Software Update pane in System Preferences, and running it from there.